# There are two text files. I need to add to the first file, after the line with the specified number n, the contents of the second file

Tags: ruby, file-io

In the beginning, I wanted to copy the text from the first file, after line n, to a variable, then deleted the contents of the first file after line n. Then inserted the contents of the second file at the end of the resulting first file(which does not contain a line after the n line). Next, after the inserted lines of the second file, insert the lines that I copied at the beginning. But now I don't know how to delete lines after line n.

I ask for help, please.

```
num= open('H:/1.txt').read.count("\n") #looking for the number of lines in the file
enum = IO.foreach(File.join("H:/1.txt"))
f = File.open("H:/1.txt")
 
n = 3 #the string n c to copy to the variable
lines = []
until n>num do
    lines<< enum.take(n)[-1] 
  
    n +=1;
  
end
p lines
```

Comment: Are the files big?

Comment: File is not big.

Comment: "But now I don't know how to delete lines after line n." - you don't need to. Just write over them.